# Is status code 200 sent after all code has been executed?

Tags: html, http

When a web page is being rendered is the http status code 200 sent before the page is rendered or does the page need to be fully rendered until status code 200 is sent ?

Comment: The HTTP code is sent in the HTTP headers, before the code of the page.

Comment: HTTP Headers (and so the status) are sent before the body (the HTML). So before the browser receives a single bit of HTML, the browser already has the status code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status code is unrelated to the page being rendered; the status code is returned by the server as a response to a request for a resource (like the HTML page). It's a way for the server to tell the browser "hey, I found the thing you asked for and here it is".

That arrives at the browser as one of the first pieces of information in the headers of the page data coming back from the server. What the browser does with this page data, and how and when it renders it, happens afterwards and is not connected with the server who has no knowledge of the browser.

Answer (score 2):

According to the RFC 2616,

> **[6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-6) Response**
>
> After receiving and interpreting a request message, a server responds
> with an HTTP response message.
>
> **[6.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-6.1) Status-Line**
>
> The first line of a Response message is the Status-Line, consisting of
> the protocol version followed by a numeric status code and its
> associated textual phrase
>
> **[6.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-6.1.1) Status Code and Reason Phrase**
>
> The Status-Code element is a 3-digit integer result code of the
> attempt to understand and satisfy the request. These codes are fully
> defined in [section 10](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10).

So the status codes are sent at the beginning of the response, before the actual content.

Comment: @Orial thanks for ref to RFC 2616 but I do not see in this doc where it explains that the status code is sent before the content is rendered. (although by the answers it highly likely is)

Comment: @blue-sky "*The **first line** of a **Response** message is the Status-Line, **consisting of** the protocol version followed by a numeric **status code** and its associated textual phrase*"

Answer (score 1):

The status code is the very first thing sent to the client browser before anything else. You can see this in your browser's developer tools "network" tab.

Answer (score 0):

This is the schema of a general HTTP response.

Statuts line
General header
Response header
Entity header
-Empty line-
-message body-

Next, the browser read all and renders the respons. The status code and the body are sended together but status code is the first line.

Read more: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html